# How can I execute Terraform code partially?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I have created an infrastructure with terraform and now I need to setup a CI... I'm thinking of using terraform also. Is it possible to extract certain part of `tf` code to place to Pipeline in order of updating ECS tasks ignoring the rest of infrastructure?

Comment: You can use `-target` but this is an escape hatch as mentioned in the docs. If you want to only apply part of your infrastructure you should break it up into separate directories and state files. In general this is a good idea anyway as otherwise it's difficult to scale your infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

As `ydaetskcoR` suggested in a comment, if you really want to run parts of your Terraform configuration independently of the rest, you're better off splitting it up.

What I'd suggest is several terraform projects grouped in the way you'd organize responsibility and releases, (e.g. projects might have their own, VPC might be on its own, some shared infrastructure in its own), and use Terraform remote state to connect them all.